# how to open the google calendar application programatically with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have tried opening the google calendar application by using the url_launcher plugin in flutter, the script is as below:

```
if (await canLaunch('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/2019/1/24')) {
  await launch('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/month/2019/1/24');
  } else {
  throw 'Could not launch URL';
}
```

in the code there was no error, but what happened was that I instead accessed google calendar through a browser not through the application.

why does that happen, is there another alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried device calendar package? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_calendar

Comment: Do you want to only open a specific day or add an event?

Comment: F-1 never before, I'll try it first
@shadowsheep I just want to open one specific day, do you have any idea?

Comment: @F-1 never, before, i'll try first..

Comment: @DenisRamdan Nope. I've found some (not official) docs for custom URI to add an event, but nothing to open the calendar on a particular day.

Answer (score 0):

i know its late to answer this but someone get help from this:-

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?dates=20210226T033000/20210226T040000&ctz=Asia/Calcutta&location&text=Blawsome:+A+Crystal+Alchemy+Healing+Meditation&details=Parth+Pitroda
```

just change this based on your requirement :)

if you want to test this google event then just copy and hit this.

Comment: This opens the stock iOS Calendar app on iOS, not Google Calendar

Comment: I have a Linux system and android device sorry I'm not able to test this in ios.

Answer (score 0):

i found this reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9ifjz7/all_google_app_urls_and_callback_urls/) with google app urls and this is working fine for me `com.google.calendar://?action=create&title={{Title}}&description={{Description}}&location={{Location}}&add={{email,anotheremail}}&isallday={{0}}`